# Does 202 status code indicate that the server cannot handle the increased traffic?

Tags: node.js, express, https, http-status-codes

I have read from these sources:

1. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202

I am maintaining an API for internal use in our organization. Recently, I got to know one person was getting a 202 response instead of a 200. But when I personally examined it, I did not get a 202, also there is no possible bug in the code.

Or is it occurring only due to the execution of the logic is taking time?

This is happening for *get requests*, but I have not set the status code to 202 programmatically.

Any suggestion gratefully accepted. Thanks in advance.

---

#### Edit after first comment [#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71581671/does-202-status-code-indicate-that-the-server-cannot-handle-the-increased-traffi?noredirect=1#comment126523871_71581671)

The API is built using `express.js`. This is what I am doing:

```js
router.get('/path/url', middleware, controller)
```

```js
//controller
exports.controller = async (req, res) => {
   //some code using await keyword
}
```

**Is it possible that because I am using async functions as controllers, 202 status code is being sent.**

Comment: I don't think so. 202 status code means that the request was successful and the request is scheduled for processing purposes.
In cases when you have performance problems you might expect errors like 4xx or 5xx.

202 status code is used in case of async processing

Comment: @DawidLewandowski I have edited the question. Please see it once.